# Implementing Extra and setData to OnClickListener on SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android

I have this SimpleCursorAdapter for my ListView, the view is set from NewView. **I'm trying to make that everytime the row is clicked, it leads to a new activity carrying the row's attribute to the new activity.**

Normally I do this with OnItemClickListener, but since I'm using SimpleCursorAdapter and NewView, the only option I got to make the row clickable is by using OnClickListener.

But I have difficulty in implementing the method I used to have on OnItemClickListener to OnClickListener. Especially I have no idea how I deal with 'id' and 'position' on OnCLick.

Here's the OnItemClickListener I used to have:

```
protected void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Intent listIntent = new Intent(ProjectsList.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            listIntent.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.position",position);
            listIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    Provider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), Long
                    .toString(id)));
            startActivity(listIntent);}
```

And here's my SimpleCursorAdapter Class:

```
class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
            Context context=null;
            ImageLoader loader = null;
            private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
            private int mProjectNameIndex = -1;
            private int mOrgNameIndex = -1;
            private int mDescIndex = -1;
            private int mDonationIndex = -1;
            private int mSmallImageIndex = -1;
            private int mKeywordIndex = -1;
            private int mPriceIndex = -1;
            private int mShortcodeIndex = -1;



            public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                    String[] from, int[] to) {
                super(context, layout, c, from, to);
                loader = new ImageLoader(context);
                this.context = context;

                mInflater = getLayoutInflater();    
                mProjectNameIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.Project.C_PROJECTTITLE);
                mOrgNameIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.Project.C_ORGANIZATIONTITLE);
                mDescIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.Project.C_PROJECTDESCRIPTION);
                mDonationIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.Project.C_DONATIONAMOUNT);
                mSmallImageIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.Project.C_SMALLIMAGE);
                mKeywordIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.Project.C_KEYWORD);
                mPriceIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.Project.C_PRICE);
                mShortcodeIndex = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Database.Project.C_SHORTCODE);

            }

            @Override
            public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                View convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitems, null);
                convertView.setClickable(true);
                convertView.setFocusable(true);
                convertView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.menuitem_background);

                convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View view) {


                } 
                      });   




                return convertView;
            }
```

Here's the line which tells that everytime the row is clicked it has to go to a new activity carrying its attributes:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(View view) {


                } 
                      });
```

I'm a newbie in this one, I really need a solution to deal with the difficulty I'm facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any issues with using onItemClickListener on a ListView that uses a SimpleCursorAdapter.

newView effectively does the same thing as another adapter's getView as far as the ListView is concerned - they both give Views that are used as rows in the list, and the ListView provides the onItemClickListener interface independently of the adapter.

However, manually setting the View to be click-able may intercept the touch event intended for onItemClick so try your old onItemClickListener and don't call

```
convertView.setClickable(true);
```

UPDATED:
Change the line in your newView method to:

```
  convertView.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(context, cursor.getString(mProjectNameIndex), convertView.getId()));
```

which uses this class:

```
class ClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    Intent listIntent;

    public ClickListener(Context c, String name, long id) {
        listIntent = new Intent(c, DetailsActivity.class);
        listIntent.putExtra("spendino.de.ProjectDetail.name", name);
        listIntent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                Provider.CONTENT_URI, Database.Project.NAME), Long
                .toString(id)));
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.getContext().startActivity(listIntent);
    }
}
```

Also override bindView in your adapter (this is because Views created in newView can be reused).

```
@Override
public void bindView (View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    if(view != null) {
        view.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener(context, cursor.getString(mProjectNameIndex), view.getId()));
    }
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
}
```

Comment: I had to declare that beacuse I inflate the View, since I have a button on each row. Both the list row and button have to be clickable. I've tried to call: convertView.setOnItemClickListener(this); it doesn't help because the method OnItemClickListener is undefined for the type NewView

Comment: Ah, I see. A Button inside a View does change things somewhat. Will update my answer

Comment: Also, you'll have to change your DetailActivity to take a name rather than the position (or whatever uniquely ids your cursor rows).

Comment: so you suggested me to create a new class which is ClickListener? I've done that but then I receive an error here:  startActivity(listIntent);

Comment: Sorry, updated answer - that should be v.getContext().startActivity(listIntent);

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work I receive errors instead, the app crashes :( it looks like it doesn't fit with the construction of my DetailsActivity class

Comment: You may have missed this comment:
"Also, you'll have to change your DetailActivity to take a name rather than the position (or whatever uniquely ids your cursor rows)."

Basically, use whatever uniquely identifies the thing you're trying to get the details of, rather than it's position in the list. I used the project name as that was the first listed, but I don't know your data structure so whatever makes sense - you'll have to update the DetailActivity to accept the new identifier instead of the position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a View's [getTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag%28int%29) and [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) methods to assign custom values to a View.  You can use these for your 'id' & 'position' - assign them in your newView() method and pull them out in the onClick method.

Comment: thanks can you provide me the code instead to make it clearer? I'm still a newbie